# XML response with JAXB and interface projection

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, spring-data-jpa

I wish to return an `XML` response of an entity subset. I use `JAXB` along with interface projection and Spring `JPA`. My entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Constants.ENTITY_TABLE_PREFIX + "ENTRY")
public class Entry implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "customer", nullable = true)
private String customer;

@Column(name = "ip_address", nullable = false)
private String ip_address;

/* Constructors, setters, getters */

}
```

Now my repository `EntryDAO` Class is:

```
//This is an example for a Spring Data JPA repository
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface EntryDAO extends JpaRepository<Entry, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT distinct e.customer as name from Entry e")
  public List<CustomerDto> findCustomer();

  @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
  public interface CustomerDto {

   @XmlAttribute
   public String getName();

  }

 }
```

and the endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class EntryXMLEndpoint {

@Autowired
private IEntryXMLService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/restxml", produces = { "application/xml" })
public CustomerDto findCustomers() {

  List<CustomerDto> o = service.findCustomer();

  CustomerDto record = o.get(0);

  return record;
}

}
```

It works fine if i choose to return a json response, but when producing xml it throws `"XML Parsing Error: element not found error"`. Any feedback would be useful.

Comment: Assuming the default JAXB marshaller is being used, JAXB (2.0) can bind XML documents to classes only, not interfaces. See [JAXB 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxb-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/jaxb-2_0-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1536924102_346278c6b0967454716fbadb59737541); specifically section 3.3 and the first note on page 20.

Comment: any alternative?

Comment: Use a class instead of an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JPA constructor expression instead.

```
@Query("SELECT new <YourPackageName>.CustomerDto(e.customer) from Entry e group by e.customer")
public List<CustomerDto> findCustomer();
```

and the DTO as class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class CustomerDto {

  private String name;

  public CusomterDto(String name) {
      this.name = name;
  } 

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getName();

}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer , it works indeed by using a class instead of an interface, the thing is that using projection one can use queries like         @Query("SELECT DISTINCT e.customer as name, e.ip_address as ip_address from Entry e") lets say in case the CustomerDto had an additional XmlAttribute, i.e ip_adress. I am not sure I can achieve this with JPA constructor ..

Comment: you can create a constructor with these arguments. A class can have many constructors

Comment: indeed ! my problem is I get a "ResultTransformer" exception when using distinct with JPA constructor, which is irrelevant to the question of course

Comment: you could use group by instead of distinct. i updated the answer